# How can I get a IP's domain?

Tags: ip, domain

We know the domain can resolve to a IP address. 
and we can use the `nslookup` tool to get a domain's IP address.

How can I get the domain of a IP?

I mean when I provide a IP, then I can get the domain.

---

**EDIT-01**

When I use the `nslookup <x.x.x.x>`, I can not get its domain.

```
[root@localhost ~]# nslookup 40.224.226.185
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find 185.226.224.40.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN
```

Comment: You can get DNS record of an IP-address by using `nslookup`. Just do `nslookup <x.x.x.x>`.

Comment: there are a LOT of "if's" in this answer.  are you trying to do something specific?

Comment: Please read https://serverfault.com/questions/41064/whats-the-command-line-utility-in-windows-to-do-a-reverse-dns-look-up. There's a explanation why it didn't work. You probably get better results with `dig`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, there is simply no such thing as "an IP's domain", because the relationship is not one-to-one, it's many-to-many. A domain can point to many addresses, and many domains can point to the same address, and many addresses can point to the same domain, and an address can point to many domains.

---

Second, DNS does not have automatic inverse lookups ("find all domains which point to this address"). That was once planned, in the very early days, but soon [abandoned](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3425) – DNS is a distributed system with millions of domain nameservers, and it would be impossible to even list all nameservers, much less query them all.

Instead, DNS only has static reverse lookups ("what domain does this address point back to?" aka rDNS), and the difference is that reverse lookup data is managed *manually* – there is **no** automatic bidirectional relationship between an address and a domain name. It is entirely up to the address owner to create the reverse lookup data, and many admins simply *don't* do that.

---

So the commands `nslookup <addr>` or `host <addr>` are correct, but they can only show what information was provided by the address owner (which might be wrong, outdated, or missing). There is *no* command that automatically finds all domains pointing to the address.

(`nslookup a.b.c.d` is a shortcut – in reality it's translated to `nslookup -q=PTR d.c.b.a.in-addr.arpa`, and similar for IPv6 using in6.arpa.)

And in the case where many domains point to a single address, you will *almost never* find that address pointing back to all those domains. If the address has reverse DNS at all, then it'll usually point to just one domain that describes the server itself, not any websites hosted on it.

Comment: so, there is no exact way to find a domain by a IP address, right?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the domain of a IP?

Short answer: You may not be able to do so. There is no requirement that IP addresses provide a reverse lookup, so there are many IP addresses that do not have any reverse DNS lookup zone associated with them.

Long answer: DNS was really designed to do look ups from a human readable name to an IP address. When you do normal DNS query, say for "www.my-example.com", the DNS query is actually a series of queries from least specific to most specific asking "what is the IP address of host www in domain example.com?" It may look a bit like this (simplistic):

- The root servers are asked for information about "com"
- The "com" servers are asked for information about "my-example"
- The "my-example" servers are asked for information about "www"
- You get a response of "1.2.3.4"

However, this won't work well when you do a DNS query for an IP address, such as 1.2.3.4 mainly because unlike a host/domain/URL, the most specific information point is at the end. So DNS changes things a bit and asks "what is the server and domain of host 4 in 3.2.1.IN-ADDR-ARPA?" which may look more like this (simplistic):

- The "IN-ADDR-ARPA" servers are asked for information about "3.2.1"
- The "3.2.1" servers are asked for information about "4"
- You get a response of "www.my-example.com"

Take note, that while one server may contain the information for both the "my-example.com" zone and the "3.2.1.IN-ADDR-ARPA" zones, they could also be two different servers.

Further, it is often the case that the servers are run by two different companies. For instance, if you pay CompanyX to host your website on their server, you may control the DNS zone for your domain pointing to the IP address of CompanyX's server (which may be hosting many different domains from different clients) but CompanyX controls the zone for the reverse lookup of the IP address. Their reverse lookup for that IP address (if it exists) would likely reflect a server/domain of CompanyX's.

Even when an entity is entitled to control both the forward and reverse zones, they are not required to provide DNS services for either. You are perfectly within your rights to register a domain name and not provide any DNS service for it.

The end result is that this means that even if you do get a response to a reverse lookup, it may have no relation to the domain name of the service you are accessing. You may be accessing "www.my-example.com" but the reverse lookup of that IP address may give you "server37.companyx.com" or something else entirely.

**Note:** Most of this answer was copied from [my own answer posted here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/25424/33).